# pip install already downloaded wheel (scons) seems slow

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, scons

On a fresh python3.7 virtual environment I try to install a downloaded wheel but the installation step on Windows takes ~20 seconds (on linux is a bit faster but still ~20seconds)

### Executed steps

Here I create venv, update pip, setuptools & wheel, download scons, nothing really interesting here.

```
PS C:\s\tmp> C:\Python37\python.exe -m venv venv37

PS C:\s\tmp> .\venv37\Scripts\activate

(venv37) PS C:\s\tmp> pip install -U pip setuptools wheel
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\s\tmp\venv37\lib\site-packages (20.1.1)
Collecting setuptools
  Using cached setuptools-49.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (789 kB)
Collecting wheel
  Using cached wheel-0.34.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
Installing collected packages: setuptools, wheel
  Attempting uninstall: setuptools
    Found existing installation: setuptools 47.1.0
    Uninstalling setuptools-47.1.0:
      Successfully uninstalled setuptools-47.1.0
Successfully installed setuptools-49.1.0 wheel-0.34.2

(venv37) PS C:\s\tmp> Measure-Command { pip download scons | Out-Default }
Collecting scons
  Using cached SCons-4.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (4.0 MB)
  Saved c:\s\tmp\scons-4.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pywin32>=1.0; platform_system == "Windows"
  Using cached pywin32-228-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (9.1 MB)
  Saved c:\s\tmp\pywin32-228-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Collecting setuptools
  Using cached setuptools-49.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (789 kB)
  Saved c:\s\tmp\setuptools-49.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
Successfully downloaded scons pywin32 setuptools

Seconds           : 2

(venv37) PS C:\s\tmp> ls
    Directory: C:\s\tmp
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----        7/10/2020   2:38 PM                venv37
-a----        7/10/2020   2:40 PM        9100091 pywin32-228-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
-a----        7/10/2020   2:40 PM        3970271 SCons-4.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
-a----        7/10/2020   2:40 PM         789761 setuptools-49.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

Here I try to install the downloaded wheel, which takes up to 17 seconds.

```
(venv37) PS C:\s\tmp> Measure-Command { python -m pip install -vvv -U --no-index --find-links . scons | Out-Default }
Non-user install because user site-packages disabled
Ignoring indexes: https://pypi.org/simple
Created temporary directory: C:\Users\FRANCE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-ephem-wheel-cache-56rg4dkw
Created temporary directory: C:\Users\FRANCE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-tracker-awspyjg9
Initialized build tracking at C:\Users\FRANCE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-tracker-awspyjg9
Created build tracker: C:\Users\FRANCE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-tracker-awspyjg9
Entered build tracker: C:\Users\FRANCE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-tracker-awspyjg9
Created temporary directory: C:\Users\FRANCE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1_k389zs
Looking in links: .
0 location(s) to search for versions of scons:
Skipping link: not a file: . (from -f)
Skipping link: wrong project name (not scons): file:///C:/s/tmp/pywin32-228-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Found link file:///C:/s/tmp/SCons-4.0.0-py3-none-any.whl, version: 4.0.0
Skipping link: wrong project name (not scons): file:///C:/s/tmp/setuptools-49.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
Skipping link: not a file: file:///C:/s/tmp/venv37
Local files found: C:\s\tmp\SCons-4.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
Given no hashes to check 1 links for project 'scons': discarding no candidates
Using version 4.0.0 (newest of versions: 4.0.0)
Processing c:\s\tmp\scons-4.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
  Added scons from file:///C:/s/tmp/SCons-4.0.0-py3-none-any.whl to build tracker 'C:\\Users\\FRANCE~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-tracker-awspyjg9'
  Removed scons from file:///C:/s/tmp/SCons-4.0.0-py3-none-any.whl from build tracker 'C:\\Users\\FRANCE~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-tracker-awspyjg9'
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: setuptools in c:\s\tmp\venv37\lib\site-packages (from scons) (49.1.0)
0 location(s) to search for versions of pywin32:
Found link file:///C:/s/tmp/pywin32-228-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl, version: 228
Skipping link: wrong project name (not pywin32): file:///C:/s/tmp/SCons-4.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
Local files found: C:\s\tmp\pywin32-228-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Given no hashes to check 1 links for project 'pywin32': discarding no candidates
Using version 228 (newest of versions: 228)
Processing c:\s\tmp\pywin32-228-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
  Added pywin32>=1.0; platform_system == "Windows" from file:///C:/s/tmp/pywin32-228-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (from scons) to build tracker 'C:\\Users\\FRANCE~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-tracker-awspyjg9'
  Removed pywin32>=1.0; platform_system == "Windows" from file:///C:/s/tmp/pywin32-228-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (from scons) from build tracker 'C:\\Users\\FRANCE~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-tracker-awspyjg9'
Installing collected packages: pywin32, scons
  Created temporary directory: C:\Users\FRANCE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-unpacked-wheel-vwh0ebm3

  Created temporary directory: C:\Users\FRANCE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-unpacked-wheel-dxib5q_u

Successfully installed pywin32-228 scons-4.0.0
Removed build tracker: 'C:\\Users\\FRANCE~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-tracker-awspyjg9'


Seconds           : 17
```

Is there anything I can do to speed up the installation step?

### Update (7.13.2020):

After bdbaddog's comment I shortly had a look at the repo, as he suggested dobook artifacts seem to be the ones to blame for this slow installation.

```
(venv37) PS C:\src\scons\SCons> dust
 397K   ┌── Node                          │                           █ │   2%
 522K   │     ┌── RELEASE-NOTES.xml       │  ░░▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓█ │   3%
 612K   │     ├── manpages                │  ░░▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓█ │   3%
 666K   │     ├── RELEASE-NOTES.html      │  ░░▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓█ │   3%
 696K   │     ├── webhelp                 │  ░░▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓█ │   3%
 417K   │     │ ┌── template-pages.xml    │  ░░▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓██ │   2%
 860K   │     ├─┴ roundtrip               │  ░░▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓██ │   4%
 876K   │     ├── slides                  │  ░░▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓██ │   4%
 919K   │     ├── params                  │  ░░▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓██ │   4%
 1.1M   │     │ ┌── reference.xml.included│  ░░▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓██ │   6%
 1.2M   │     ├─┴ docsrc                  │  ░░▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓██ │   6%
 1.3M   │     ├── xhtml-1_1               │  ░░▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓██ │   7%
 1.3M   │     ├── xhtml                   │  ░░▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓██ │   7%
 1.6M   │     ├── html                    │  ░░▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓███ │   8%
 447K   │     │ ┌── param.xml             │  ░░▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓███ │   2%
 1.8M   │     ├─┴ fo                      │  ░░▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓███ │   9%
 3.1M   │     ├── common                  │  ░░▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓█████ │  15%
  16M   │   ┌─┴ docbook-xsl-1.76.1        │  ░░████████████████████████ │  83%
  16M   │ ┌─┴ docbook                     │  ░░████████████████████████ │  83%
  17M   ├─┴ Tool                          │  ██████████████████████████ │  89%
  20M ┌─┴ .                               │████████████████████████████ │ 100%
```

Comment: For me `pip download` took about 2 seconds and `pip install` about 1. Please provide your full logs after `pip install -vvv` so we can see what's going on. BTW did `pip download` downloaded a wheel for you? Wheels are installed almost instantly and without a wheel `pip` builds a wheel from source code.

Comment: Fair request, I tried to keep the post short, but maybe too much. I updated post, download is no problem for me either. Indeed a whl file is downloaded. Install still took 17 seconds this time, not sure why is now 10 seconds shorter. BTW in CI (azure devops) I have a similar problem. 

The linux box where I tested was WSL which adds it's own overhead to the file system, so maybe what I wrote "pip install on linux" was not a fair/realistic.

Comment: It seems `pip install pywin32` takes so long. I'm on Linux.

Comment: Is 20 seconds really an issue? The second time the package should already be downloaded and be faster right?

Comment: So 4.0.0 wheel now includes extra files which should have always been in the wheel for docbook builder. That adds significantly to the size of the wheel. That could be part of the reason it's slower to install. Please come to the SCons discord channel  (https://discord.gg/bXVpWAy) or irc #scons on freenode and I'll try to construct one without..

Comment: You are right cloning scons, deleting folder `.\SCons\Tool\docbook\` and making a new wheel `python setup.py bdist_wheel` is already much faster. Pip installing this wheel without docbook took just _2 seconds_.

Comment: In the example I download the wheel therefore the first installation is already "offline".

Locally 20 seconds is not an issue, I'm fine with it.
**Context**: In our CI pipelines is a different story, scons is part of our build process and needed at a very early stage (many other stages are waiting for this), it needs to be installed on every push in our team. In CI it's not a deal-breaker but the issue gets growing as we have more pipelines.

Comment: There are people watching here as you've seen, but sending a summary of this somewhere on the project - scons-users mailing list for example - would help tracking. Seems like fixing the bug that had omitted to docbook files had... consequences (fancy that!).

Comment: tried to subscribe to the mailing-list, but no success so far, I believe my request is waiting for approval ... Do you mind if I open an issue directly on github? Or is the mailing list the place to go?